# How can I use iOS Google Chrome to scan a QR code into an input field?

Tags: ios, forms, google-chrome, web, qr-code

### QR Feature

The newest version of Google Chrome for iOS boasts a new button on the keyboard to scan QR codes:

[image: iPad QR Code interface]

### Can this be used on a web form?

This seems to work when searching from the address bar but not on text inputs on web forms. Is there some form or input attribute I can use to enable the QR code for an input?

### Other ideas?

If the answer is no how else might I scan QR code data into the input of a web form?

I'd like to make it as easy as possible for the end user and hope to do it with on a web page instead of writing an app.